# How to: print paragraph title centered, and on a shaded line across the page?

Tags: environments, multicol, sections-paragraphs

For a cheat sheet I am making I would like that `\paragraph{title}` does the following:

1. Centre the text 'title',
2. on a shaded (gray) line across the entire page ( column in my case ),
3. start the actual text in the paragraph without an indent.

Is this possible? If so, how should I set this up?

Comment: `\par{title}` ????

Comment: \paragraph or any name actually

Comment: minimal example missing. A solution is dependent on the class in use.

Comment: Since this is a cheat sheet, you could define your own command, which is much much simpler than changing a sectioning command. Much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are not using any KOMA class and your paragraph titles don't run in to more than one line, here is an example with `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% for demo
\usepackage{lipsum}      %% for demo
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\colorbox{gray!40}{\makebox[\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax]{\filcenter #1\strut}}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{\mytitle}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \paragraph{Title}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution, assuming you are using a KOMA class.

I used section here, instead of paragraph.

[image: ndrookKomaSectionColor]

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,DIV=18]{scrartcl}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=-1ex,
    afterskip=1ex,
]{section}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{sectioncolor}{gray}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
    \hspace*{#2}%
    \colorbox{sectioncolor}{%
        \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-#2\relax}{%
            \raggedsection\color{white}\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{6}
    \section{ant}
    \blindtext[2]
    \section{bee}
    \blindtext
    \section{cat}
    \blindtext
    \section{Penguins and Dixie dancing ducks}
    \blindtext
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may note that this needs a recent KOMA version. Am I right?

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, it does. But i am not sure how recent.