# How to: print paragraph title centered, and on a shaded line across the page? - Continued

Tags: environments, multicol, sections-paragraphs

This question is a continuation of: [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273662/how-to-print-paragraph-title-centered-and-on-a-shaded-line-across-the-page)

Consider the following document

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage[a3paper, textwidth=5cm, margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\colorbox{gray!40}{\makebox[\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax]{\filcenter #1\strut}}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{\mytitle}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}



\begin{document}

\paragraph{Cheat Sheet Number Theory}

\begin{multicols}{6}
\paragraph{Divisibility}
- This is a test line.
\paragraph{Congruences}
- This is a test line 1.\\
- This is a test line 2.

\columnbreak
\paragraph{Arithmetic Functions}

- This is a test line.

\columnbreak
col C\\
\paragraph{Quadratic Residues}
%-
This is another test line.

\columnbreak
col D \\
%\paragraph{Continued Fractions}
Test

%\paragraph{Pell Equation}
%-

%\paragraph{Diophantine Equations}
%-

\columnbreak
col E \\
%\paragraph{Number Fields}
Test

 \columnbreak
 col F \\
 %\paragraph{Analytic Number Theory}
 Test 

 \end{multicols}

 \end{document}

 %\begin{center}
 %  \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 %      \hline
 %      cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 %      cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 %      cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 %      \hline
 %  \end{tabular}
 %\end{center}
```

I have applied the accepted answer as given for the related question mention above.

Now, columns A, D, E and F appear as expected, columns B and C however appear not as expected:
- below the paragraph 'Arithmetic Functions' 5 extra lines are printed. The column should appear as column A.
- in column C, below the text 'col C' empty lines appear of which I do not understand where they come from.

How to fix this?

Comment: That did the trick. If you make it an answer with a short explanation of why this has to be done I can upvote and accept it and normally close the question.

Comment: That was fast :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns under [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) are necessarily balanced (referred to as `\flushcolumns`). It seems you're after an unbalanced view in this case. That is, an issue of `\columnbreak` should break the column without any vertical adjustment. For this, add

```
\raggedcolumns
```

to your preamble.